# How to get display style in both numerator/denominator in a fraction?

Tags: math-mode, fractions

Test code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  z = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N{x_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^N{y_i}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  z = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^N{x_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^N{y_i}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  z = \tfrac{\sum_{i=1}^N{x_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^N{y_i}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

results in equations that look like this:

[image]

They all just look like different variations of a compressed style as opposed to what I get if I use this:

```
\begin{equation}
    z = \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^N{x_i}}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^N{y_i}}
\end{equation}
```

which results in:

[image]

Is sprinkling `\displaystyle` around the only get to get this last style?

Comment: `\dfrac` tells TeX to use display style for the fraction, which means using `\textstyle` for numerator and denominator. If you're under `\displaystyle`, there's no difference between `\frac` and `\dfrac`.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. So if I want the equation displayed in the last style, am I relegate to adding `\displaystyle` in both numerator and denominator?

Comment: `\newcommand\ddfrac[2]{\dfrac{\displaystyle#1}{\displaystyle#2}}` then use `ddfrac`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in a display, such as `equation`, there's no difference between `\frac` and `\dfrac`; LaTeX will typeset the fraction with numerator and denominator in text style, which accounts for the placement of limits in the summation.

You can define a `\Dfrac` command:

```
\newcommand{\Dfrac}[2]{%
  \dfrac{\displaystyle #1}{\displaystyle #2}%
}
```

if you really need such big objects.

The general rule is that numerator and denominator in a fraction are typeset in the immediately following style of the current one:

> display → text
>   text → script
>   script → scriptscript
>   scriptscript → scriptscript

With `\dfrac` or `\tfrac` you only override the current style, to use respectively display and text style.